# $ N $ is an elementary abelian $ p $-subgroup. Is true $ N $ is cyclic group? $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is solvable group and $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of $ G $. Let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $, then $ N $ is an elementary abelian $ p $-subgroup. Is true $ N $ is cyclic group? $

If $ M_{G} = 1 $, that $ M_{G} $ is the core of $ M $ in $ G $, then $ M \cap N = 1 $ since $ M \cap N \lhd G $ ?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the group 
$$(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_3,$$
where $C_3$ act by permuting the elements of order $2$ in $C_2\times C_2$.
Then
$$N=C_2\times C_2$$
which is not cyclic.